# performing a subquery in an each in M language in Power BI

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am converting SQL in various flavors into Power BI.  I have the following query/code which I am trying to represent in the M syntax:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rate = SELECT CAD FROM ExchangeRate WHERE date<='" . $row['d'] . "' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
    $monthlySalesUSD += $daily/$rate;
}
```

Basically, it looks up the exchange rate for the date of a particular set of transactions, then divides the sales figures for that day by the exchange rate for that day.

In Power BI Advanced Query, I have the following excerpt defined:

```
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "SalesUSD", each [Inserted Rounding] / List.First(Table.Column(Table.First(Table.SelectRows(Table.Sort(warehouse_ExchangeRate,{{"date", Order.Descending}}),each [date] <= #"Changed Type"[DATELASTFULFILLMENT])),"CAD"))),
```

`#"Changed Type"` Contains the daily transaction totals and the dates.  The totals are in `[Inserted Rounding]` and the dates are in `[DATELASTFULFILLMENT]`.  So basically, for each row in  `#"Changed Type"`, I want to get the date, look up the exchange rate, then divide the sales by that rate.  The piece I cannot seem to get is how to pull in the date from the current row in the each.

Comment: A better way to go in Power Query: merge the tables first and then add the column with Sales in USD. Afterwards, you can simply delete the columns that are no longer required (like the exchange rate column).

Comment: A merge though assumes equality of the operators, e.g., exchangerate.date = sales.datelastfulfilled. However, my use case is such that I need the closest match, because the cron job that fetches the exchange rates does not fire daily.  In other words, there are missing dates, and I need the exchange rate that is equal to or before the sales date.  Unless there is a way to do a NestedJoin (what a Merge performs in M) with unequal conditionals that I am unaware of (very likely, as I am still learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to [MarcelBeug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7163813/marcelbeug) pointing me in the right direction.  I found [this post](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/joinAlgorithm-and-keyEqualityComparers/td-p/110108) which led me to the fact that you can do lambdas in an add column.  This gave me the following steps:

```
#"Fixed Join" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Date", "ExchangeRate",
        (Earlier) => Table.SelectRows(warehouse_ExchangeRate,
                     each [date] <= Earlier[Date])),
#"Expanded ExchangeRate" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Fixed Join", "ExchangeRate", {"CAD"}, {"CAD"})
```

This gives me the closest match that is less than the date of the sale, which I can then just divide into the sale to give me the USD value, then select the columns I need from that.